# Chromium wasting almost all my bandwidth

Tags: chromium, ubuntu-15.10

I'm using Chromium 49.0.2623.108 on Ubuntu 15.10, and I have noticed for the last few days that, every day, Chromium wastes almost all my bandwidth during a long part of the day (around 10 Mbps).

I have checked the Chromium Task Manager (Shift+Esc), and it doesn't show anything. I have then run the command `sudo nethogs enp2s0` and it shows the process *31752*. Upon checking the Chromium Task Manager again, I can see that process *31752* is the main Chromium process.

Then I run `sudo iftop -i enp2s0`, and it shows that the IP address from where Chromium is downloading data is **168.62.188.213**, which belongs to Microsoft Corporation.

But the real problem is that I have no idea of what exactly is causing this, or what is being downloaded! There are no active downloads in the browser either.

Comment: `168.62.188.213` is an Azure address. Owned by Microsoft but probably rented by a third-party. Google probably wouldn't rent an Azure server. Have you checked what extensions you have installed?

Comment: Im really wanting to know more about this. Any other details you have on this is it using any other resources? The site looks like it uses bitcoin,dogecoin,dashcoin and Litecoin. Looked at thier traffic per day which can be found [Here](http://www.cutestat.net/bitcointoyou.com) and [Here](http://www.iwebsiteworth.com/www/bitcointoyou.com) which make me wonder if they are using your computer to get views per day as well as something else not sure why they would use their websites ip address though.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior You can look at the network tab of the devtools (press F12 to open) and check what any specific Chrome tab is requesting. Not sure about the 10 Mbps though... what does this site do?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to mind is using Chrome's in browser tools. You can try to navigate to `Chrome://net-internals/#events` which will show you the network events. You can also navigate to other tabs through the drop-down on the top to poke around. With out further information, cannot really tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The `168.62.188.213` address is a server hosted on Azure, which is owned by Microsoft but usually rented out to others.

In fact, it looks like it's Bitcoin-related.

Have you checked your extensions? It sounds like a rogue extension. Try disabling extensions one at a time until this usage stops, then you'll know which one caused it. You can speed up the search by disabling half at a time.